# How do I combine title and body as a filter programmatically?

Tags: 7, views

Attached upon the existing exposed filter, this code enables title and body to be separately selected and to be searched separately but it needs the addition of 'all' option. I have difficulty joining title and body or adding an additional field to the query array or the `add_where()` line to bring out the result. Is there a way to solve this?

```
function combine_search_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
if ($view->name == 'news' || $view->name == 'announcement' || $view->name == 'investment') {
    $conditions = &$query->where[1]['conditions'];

if (!empty($view->exposed_input['search_box']) && $view->exposed_input['search_within'] == 'all') {
}
if (!empty($view->exposed_input['search_box']) && $view->exposed_input['search_within'] == 'title') {
// Add title filter condition if title is selected
    $query->where[1]['conditions'][] = array(
      'field' => 'node.title',
      'value' => '%' . $view->exposed_input['search_box'] . '%',
      'operator' => 'LIKE',
      );
}
if (!empty($view->exposed_input['search_box']) && $view->exposed_input['search_within'] == 'body') {
// Create join with field_data_body table.
// source:
// https://api.drupal.org/api/views/includes!handlers.inc/function/views_join%3a%3aconstruct/
// https://www.drupal.org/node/2049051#comment-7784967
    $join = new views_join;
    $extra = array();
    $extra[] = array(
      'table' => 'field_data_body',
      'field' => 'entity_type',
      'value' => 'node',
      'operator' => '=',
      );
    $extra[] = array(
      'table' => 'field_data_body',
      'field' => 'deleted',
      'value' => '0',
      'operator' => '=',
      );
    $join->construct('field_data_body', 'node', 'nid', 'entity_id', $extra);
// Add join to query; 'node' is the left table name
    $view->query->add_relationship('field_data_body',$join,'node');
// Add fields from table (or where clause, or whatever)
    $view->query->add_field('field_data_body','entity_id');
// Add body filter condition if body is selected
    $query->where[1]['conditions'][] = array(
      'field' => 'field_data_body.body_value',
      'value' => '%' . $view->exposed_input['search_box'] . '%',
      'operator' => 'LIKE',
      );
}
```